# Display selection from different joins in one

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, union

```
select 
m.messageid,    
m.message,
m.orig,     
m.recip, 
d.company as orig_company,
d.department as orig_department,
d.office as orig_office,
d.country as orig_country
from department d
join messages m 
on m.originator = d.address

select
m.messageid,    
m.message,
m.orig,     
m.recip, 
d.company as recip_company,
d.department as recip_department,
d.office as recip_office,
d.country as recip_country
from department d
join messages m 
on m.recip = d.address
```

I would like to make one selection that will have the information:

> messageid, message, orig, recip, orig_company, orig_office,
>   orig_country, orig_office, recip_company, recip_office, recip_country,
>   recip_office

How can be done? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Add both joins to one query.

Comment: What do you mean 'in one line'? Think a UNION ALL between statements is fine. A UNION when you don't need duplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL`. The important part is that both results must have the same amount of columns and data types.

```
select 
    m.messageid,    
    m.message,
    m.orig,     
    m.recip, 

    d.company as orig_company,
    d.department as orig_department,
    d.office as orig_office,
    d.country as orig_country,

    CONVERT(VARCHAR(200), NULL) AS recip_company,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(200), NULL) AS recip_department,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(200), NULL) AS recip_office,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(200), NULL) AS recip_country

from department d
    join messages m 
on m.originator = d.address

UNION ALL

select
    m.messageid,    
    m.message,
    m.orig,     
    m.recip,

    NULL as orig_company,
    NULL as orig_department,
    NULL as orig_office,
    NULL as orig_country

    d.company as recip_company,
    d.department as recip_department,
    d.office as recip_office,
    d.country as recip_country
from department d
    join messages m 
on m.recip = d.address
```

Please check if the data type `VARCHAR(200)` is OK for your case. The first query result from the `UNION` will datermine the resulting data type, that's why you need to explicitly say which type your hard-coded `NULL` will have.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :)

Comment: You need a GROUP BY to get orig values and recip values in the same rows.

Answer (score 4):

`LEFT JOIN` department table twice. First time for *orig* values, second time for *recip* values:

```
select 
m.messageid,    
m.message,
m.orig,     
m.recip, 
d1.company as orig_company,
d1.department as orig_department,
d1.office as orig_office,
d1.country as orig_country,
d2.company as recip_company,
d2.department as recip_department,
d2.office as recip_office,
d2.country as recip_country
from messages m
left join department d1
    on m.originator = d1.address
left join department d2
    on m.recip = d2.address
```

Comment: This might multiply the records if there is more than 1 match on the joining tables. Might be useful depending on the case.

Comment: @EzequielLópezPetrucci, without sample data it's hard to know. Probably fine as it is.